# Ubuntu Phone Aquaris E4.5 dead screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen

I bought a new latest Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition.
Phone is updated to Ubuntu 14.04, everything official.

Phone was working quite fine until yesterday, when sudenly screen went of an since then I can't turn it on. None of the key combinations would work, holiding, pressing... nothing works.

Turns our that the phone is actually still ON, cause when I get an incomming call it still rings. But I cant answer/deny call (as I see nothing on screen).

Any clue?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you turn it off and on again? (that would be pressing all three buttons simultaneously for 15 to 20 seconds).

Comment: SOLVED! I was holding all possible combinations.. but not for 20seconds. It helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quite the same issue on my Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition (v 15.04 OTA15).
The phone is ON and when I want wake it up, the screen become dark purple !
Finally, I press **+ button** (on the side: sound +) and simultaneously **On button** and it seams reboot and the white screen with bq logo appears, then the phone works fine again… I hope for a long time.